# Reading data with Entity Framework the right way

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables:

1. Person
2. Folders
3. PersonsFolders

There are relationships between `Person` and `PersonsFolders`, and between `Folders` and `PersonsFolders`.

Now I need to display in a gridview all folders with the first person from the array. I tried  to read data from `PersonsFolders` and I retrieved all data from person and folders  but I have every folder a few times - for each person with that folderID.

I filtered this using this code:

```
.GroupBy(t => t.FolderID)
               .Select(g => g.First())
               .ToList();
```

I also tried to select all Folders and display on xamal

```
 PersonsFolders[0].Person.Tel
```

but only got information from Folder. I was not successful in retrieval of information Person table- so that the information appears in the gridview simultaneously.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = Folders.Select(x=> new { Folder = x, Person = x.PersonFolders.OrderBy(pf => pf.person.name).first().select(pf => pf.person)}).ToList();
```

this should give you a list of with objects that have 2 properties, a property for the folder and a property for the person

i created a small example of the code above

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yBCwZC

Comment: Even with changes for adaption the code doesn't work.

Comment: Check the edit, is this what you meant with your question?

Comment: Before all really thanks.  I copied your code and it works great, but in my code with entity framework It does not work. I see the data in  system.data.entity.dynamicproxies.when i go into the code